# How do I implement a search controller like this?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

How do I do something [like this](https://gfycat.com/MammothCrazyBergerpicard)

This is what I managed to do so far, [my project](https://gfycat.com/PerfumedWaterloggedDiamondbackrattlesnake):

[This is my storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T39ES.jpg)

My search controller is in the blue view controller, and my tableview controller that I want to show the list is at the bottom left.

The search UISearchResultsUpdating delegate and the search controller itself are in the blue view controller, so how do I filter the list in my tableview controller?

Thanks

Comment: You can use `UISearchController`  search for example

Comment: I am already doing that in my project. Look at the gif.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
   `func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController){
    let search_txt = searchController.searchBar.text!.lowercased();
    self.searchedResultList.removeAll(keepingCapacity : false)` 

    self.searchedResultList = yourArrayList.filter(){
    //you code here

    }
   self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: How do I trigger this delegate function in my tablview controller? (see image) my search controller is at the blue controller, that is not a tableview controller.

Comment: In your question you mentioned "how do I filter the list in my tableview controller?".